# can't resume readable stream nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord, resume, node-streams

I'm trying to make a discord bot that plays music. To play music I use a readable stream which I get using ytdl-core. I can pause it without problem using the .pause() method but after doing that using .resume() doesn't seem to have any effect. Here is the code I use for my resume function.

```
module.exports.run =async (client, channel, authorID, args) => {
    const ServerInfos = require("../ServerInfos").ServerInfos
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        for (let i=0;i<ServerInfos.length;i++){
            if (ServerInfos[i].ID==channel.guild.id && ServerInfos[i].AudioStream != null){
                console.log(ServerInfos[i].AudioStream)
                ServerInfos[i].AudioStream.resume()
                resolve("Music resumed")
            };
        };
    })
};
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'resume',
    description:'resumes the music',
    options:[]
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by downgrading nodejs to 12.x